# Import MS Access data on a Meteor Galaxy server

Tags: node.js, ms-access, meteor, mdbtools, meteor-galaxy

I need to parse a MS Access database on a Meteor server hosted on Galaxy.
Specifically it's a .accdb file.

If I were able to install [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) on Galaxy, the npm package [mdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdb) would serve this purpose- but I'm fairly certain I can't install anything on Galaxy hosted servers.

Is there an easy solution to this or do I need to switch hosting/ set up a process on a different host to convert the database to a usable format?

---

EDIT:

I was able to install and use [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) but I wasn't able to get [mdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdb) to work on my build. I created my own implementation of [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) called [mdb-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdb-parse). This **will not work in Galaxy** but seems to me at this time to be the only solution if you need to work with .accdb and .mdb files on Node.js.

Comment: Let's start by specifying that mdbtools can't do this. It's limited to mdb files, and doesn't support accdb ones.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I am able to use mdbtools on my .accdb files without any problem.

Comment: It appears that mdbtools supports some earlier formats of accdb files (at least up to 2010) https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/77.